# how to use jquery pagination with asp.net viewmodels

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, pagination

I wonder how I can achieve pagination when working with viewModel in asp.net.
using Jquery in order to not load all table data.
Here's my project.

I have 2 tables :

Products Contains: ProductID - ProductName - ProductDescription.

Images contains :ImageID - ImagePath - ProductFK

In my ViewModel

```
public class myViewModel
{
  public List<Products> myProducts { get; set; }
  public List<Images> myImages{ get; set; }
}
```

In my Index view I have

```
@model myProject.myViewModel
@foreach (Products item in Model.myProducts)
{
@item.ProductName
@item.ProductDescription
}
```

And here's my controller that returns the list of products and Images.

```
 public ActionResult Show()
{
var viewModel = new myViewModel{
myProduct= DB.Products.ToList(),
myImages= DB.Images.ToList()};
return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: Use `Skip` and `Take`: `DB.Products.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList()`. Where `pageIndex` and `pageSize` will be provided from view by user.

Comment: @Bardr  thanksa for replying, it sounds a good idea, but I want to make pagination without any user iteraction, so once the list loads , i want a paging index where user can navigate the items of the loaded lists

Comment: @riario What you means with make pagination without any user iteraction ?

Comment: @riario Then just provide default value for pageSize yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a variable in your controller or in shared settings class to determine page size, if you want to change in future you will change in one place (or you can read it dynamic based on system settings).

```
public int pageSize
{
    get
    {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

In your view model, add new int field called **pageNumber**.
You will set this variable to tell your controller which page to fetch.

then fetch only required data from database using entity framework LINQ:

```
     public ActionResult Show()
    {
    var viewModel = new myViewModel{
    myProduct= DB.Products..ToList(),

    myImages= DB.Images.OrderBy(a => a.Id).Skip(pageSize * (pageNumber- 1))
         .Take(pageSize).ToList(); // this will fetch only required data from database
}
    return View(viewModel);
    }
```

and in your UI you need to pass page number to controller , your action will become :

```
 public ActionResult Show(int pageNumber)
{
  var viewModel = new myViewModel();
viewmodel.PageNumber = pageNumber; // pass it to view again you may need to give the selected page special css
}
```